# plumbing diagram

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, water, repair, leak

[image][image][image][image: had to resize i have more pics but it wasnt easy to do this lol]i am in need of a bathroom to kitchen from well plumbing diagram since i have no idea what im doing the bathroom has a sink toilet and tub/shower and on the otherside of the wall is the kitchen sink. |Thanku so much... KS-kitchen sink (with sprayer)BS-bathroom sink T-toilet and TUB-and shower pipes for shower are towards kitchen we had major winter damage and keep finding pipes broken somewhere else every time we put new line in.
___
|K|
*****|S|*****
|T |   |BS||
|U |       |
|B | {T}   |

---

Comment: Are you asking for someone to draw your plumbing layout in your house? You're quite likely going to need a local person to do that.

Comment: Are you planning to add a new bathroom or just want to know how the pipes are laid out in the bathroom you have?  With the damage I would guess most of your pipes are on outside walls, which is only a good idea on a topical beach.

Comment: i just need a diagram of how the pipes should be laid out ill try and get a pic of whats under my floor in the batroom

Comment: The pipes _should_ be laid out in a logical way that reduces the amount of pipe needed to supply water to all the fixtures while minimizing the number of holes through joists & studs. If you provide a floor plan of your house showing where the plumbing fixtures are, we can make some educated guesses as to where the pipes have been run, but the only way to know for sure is to open up your walls and look.

Comment: I edited and put one picture

Comment: My house was built in the 40s with mill ends so really hard to be sure things are right lol

Comment: Basically plumbing is right if water flows out of the faucets/taps and goes down the drain without leaking.  About the only thing to worry about with 1940s plumbing is leaks, those pipes are at or near end of life, and if P-traps for the sink/bathtub are done right.

Comment: What are "mill ends"? What is that coding at the end of your question? Why all the "lol"? Please edit again to include some formatting to make your question easier to read and understand - help us help you!